# Append UTM params in a href url

Tags: php, laravel

I want to find a href url from the Description string and append UTM parameters, I have tried with regex and it's working, but getting an issue when the  has a target attribute.

Here below is my logic, could anyone help me, with regex, please?

```
function AppendCampaignToString($string) {
        $regex = '#(<a href=")([^"]*)("[^>]*?>)#i';
        return preg_replace_callback($regex, '_appendCampaignToString', $string);
    }
    function _appendCampaignToString($match) {
        $url = $match[2];
        if (strpos($url, '?') === false) {
            $url .= '?';
        }
        else
        {
            $url .= '&';   
        }
        $url .= 'utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=product_notify';
        return $match[1].$url.$match[3];
    }
// Function call
$url2 = AppendCampaignToString($string);
```

Comment: what does this have to do with java?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting an issue"? Anything not working?

Comment: @NicoHaase, Yes I want to update the <a href=""> URL with UTM Parameter, so I can get new <a href="test.html?UTM=sdfsdf">asasd</a> like this.

Comment: Please add all such clarification to your question by editing. Is there anything not working?

Answer (score 0):

You must pay attention to all non-url characters (Such as space) in the anchor tag, then extract the URL exactly.

Use this regex:

```
#(\<a.+href\=\")([\w\S]+)(\".+)#i
```

Just replace this regex with your own regex.